# How do I rewrite this into MVC Razor 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, syntax

Its a simple snippet, but the .replace is not being recognize in my mvc razor view:
I replaced **<%= %>** with **@**, not sure what else is needed?

```
 <%=Ajax.ActionLink("[replacethis]", 
        "ToggleEnabled", 
                new { id = Model.ID }, 
                new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "toggleimage" + Model.ID }).Replace("[replacethis]",
                string.Format("<div id='toggleimage{0}'><img src='/Content/icons/{1}' border='0' alt='toggle'/></div>", 
                Model.ID, Model.Enabled ? "tick.png" : "tick_grey.png"))%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the ideal, but you can get what you're after by:

1. Inserting `.ToHtmlString()` (ie, convert MvcHtmlString to a raw HTML string so that you can call `Replace` on it)
2. Wrapping the whole thing in `Html.Raw()` (so that it doesn't get HTML encoded before rendering)

---

```
@Html.Raw(
    Ajax.ActionLink("[replacethis]", 
        "ToggleEnabled", 
        new { id = Model.ID }, 
        new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "toggleimage" + Model.ID })
   .ToHtmlString()
   .Replace("[replacethis]",
       string.Format("<div id='toggleimage{0}'><img src='/Content/icons/{1}' border='0' alt='toggle'/></div>", 
           Model.ID, Model.Enabled ? "tick.png" : "tick_grey.png")
   )
)
```